# How to map IEnumerable<string> convert to string?

Tags: c#

Method that accepts two Dal objects =>>

```
Method(DalFirst[] source1, DalSecond[] source2):

source1.Select(
    src => new DataExmaple()
    {
       Id = src.Id,
       ...
       AdditionalField = source2.Select(x => x.Field).ToString()
    }
```

I get the output name as just type

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[....
```

With `FirstOfDefault` => it turns out, but the same values are everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default string representation of a collection.  You'd need to specify how you want the data to render as a string.  For example, if you want each value separated by a comma (or any other delimiter) then you can join the collection values with `String.Join`:

```
AdditionalField = String.Join(",", source2.Select(x => x.Field))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this expression:

```
AdditionalField = source2.Select(x => x.Field).ToString()
```

At this point, `source2` is still the **entire** `DalSecond[] source2` array. You need to do something to map each `source1` item to the specific matching `source2` value(s). I could give you more, but there's not enough information in the question yet to infer what you really want to do here.

Comment: yes, u'r right. I need each source2 put into source1.
but i can not understand where and how to loop it...

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to do. Let's say you have 6 `source1` items and 11 `source2` items. Do you want all 11 `source2` items repeated in _each_ `source1` result, for a total of 66 entries? Do you want to try to match up the arrays by index? Which btw is an **anti-pattern**... something you should avoid and a sign you need to go back to the drawing board at a higher level of your architecture.

Comment: source1 = { "1", "2", "3", "empty_field" }
source2 = { "a", "b", "c", "e" }

output: { "1", "2", "3", "e" }

i have to compare each of items in array to another one. btw they always have same ids, yes... it's likely anti-pattern :(